# How to turn off shutting down of containers in TestContainers?

Tags: java, testcontainers

I have this abstract class for IT tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(DbUnitConfig.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = App.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@DbUnitConfiguration(dataSetLoader = DbUnitDataSetLoader.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
})
public abstract class AbstractIT {

    @ClassRule
    public static final DockerComposeContainer postgres =
        new DockerComposeContainer(new File("src/test/resources/docker-compose-postgres.yml"))
            .withExposedService("cars-user-postgres-it", 5432);

}
```

when i'm launching only one instance of IT test class, it works OK.

But when i'm launching multiple test classes, one the first will complete, other will fail because of shut down postgres

this is the log from Container:

```
Stopping 1ykxuc_postgres-it_1 ... 

Stopping 1ykxucpostgres-it_1 ... done
Removing 1ykxuc_postgres-it_1 ... 

Removing 1ykxuc_cars-user-postgres-it_1 ... done
Removing network 1ykxuc_default
```

how to tell TestContainers not to stop containers after one class execution, but when all of them finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found this solution as workaround.
Maybe there is better soultion?

```
   private static final DockerComposeContainer postgres = new DockerComposeContainer(new File("src/test/resources/docker-compose-postgres.yml"))
        .withExposedService("postgres-it", 5432);

    /**
     * static block used to workaround shutting down of container after each test class executed
     * TODO: try to remove this static block and use @ClassRule
     */
    static {
        postgres.starting(Description.EMPTY);
    }
```

yml file:

```
version: "2"
services:
cars-user-postgres-it:
    image: postgres
    ports:
        - 5432:5432
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        POSTGRES_DB: user
```

Comment: This is a recommended solution when you want to start a "singleton"-like containers (i.e. 1 container per JVM execution) :)

Comment: @bsideup thanks for your opinion! Now i know that i'm on the right way

Comment: @bsideup is the latest version (1.9.1) method starting(Description description) is marked as Deprecated. What is the recommended solution at the moment?

Comment: Just use `postgres.start();`

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible by setting the experimental `.withReuse(true)` when setting up container:

```
new GenericContainer<>(IMAGE).withExposedPorts(PORT).withReuse(true);
```

Remember to start the container with `.start()` and adding `testcontainers.reuse.enable=true` to ~/.testcontainers.properties

Reference:
https://www.testcontainers.org/features/reuse/